# If $Z\thicksim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, find the expected value of $\frac{1}{1+Z}.$

Tags: probability, solution-verification, expected-value, poisson-distribution

**The Problem:** Suppose that $Z\thicksim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Find the expected value of $\dfrac{1}{1+Z}.$

We have that
\begin{align*}
E\left[\frac{1}{1+Z}\right]&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{1+k}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}\left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}-1\right]\\
&=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}[e^\lambda-1]=\frac{1}{\lambda}-\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda},
\end{align*}
where we used the Taylor series for the exponential function.

---

Do you agree with my approach above? Any feedback is most welcomed.
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Looks good to me. Would likely use $$\frac{1 - e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}$$ for the final answer